# Suggestions to increase the speed of a fugacity calculation

Tags: performance-tuning, physics, chemistry

I'm writing code to simulate a chemical reaction. This requires the calculation of the [fugacity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fugacity) of a mixture of gases. The underlying model is the  [SRK equation of state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation_of_state#Soave_modification_of_Redlich-Kwong).

First the physical properties are declared:

```
*fugacity calculations according to SRK equation*)
(*Critical properties for selected gases*)
r = 8.314;
presc = {35.0, 73.8, 20.5, 220.5, 81.0, 33.9}*100000;
tempc = {132.9, 304.2, 43.6, 647.3, 512.6, 126.2};
volc = {93.1, 94.0, 51.5, 56.0, 118.0}*10^-6;
omegac = {0.049, 0.255, 0.0, 0.344, 0.572, 0.040};
```

The equation of state is set up:

```
(*SRK equation*)
a = 0.42748*(r*tempc)^2/presc;
b = 0.08664*(r*tempc)/presc;
alpha[temp_] = (1 + (0.480 + 1.574 omegac - 0.176 omegac^2) (1- 
Sqrt[temp/tempc]))^2;

A[temp_, pres_] = Table[(a[[i]]*alpha[temp][[i]]*pres)/(r*temp)^2, {i, 1, 
6}];

B[temp_, pres_] = Table[(b[[i]]*pres)/(r*temp), {i, 1, 6}];

Amix[temp_, pres_, yfrac_] := Sum[yfrac[[i]]*yfrac[[j]]*Sqrt[A[temp, 
pres][[i]]*A[temp, pres][[j]]], {i, 1, 6}, {j, 1, 6}];

Bmix[temp_, pres_, yfrac_] := Sum[yfrac[[i]]*B[temp, pres][[i]], {i, 1, 6}];
```

Finally, the fugacity is calculated:

(*Fugacity calculation*)

```
fugacitymix[temp_, pres_, i_, yfrac_] := With[{Amix2 = Amix[temp, pres, 
yfrac], Bmix2 = Bmix[temp, pres, yfrac]},
                        Exp[(z - 1) B[temp, pres][[i]]/Bmix2 - Log[z - 
Bmix2] - Amix2/Bmix2 (2 (A[temp, pres][[i]]/Amix2)^0.5 - 
B[temp, pres][[i]]/Bmix2) Log[1 + Bmix2/z] /. 
z -> Last[
  Cases[z /. {ToRules@NRoots[z^3 - 
         z^2 + (Amix2 - Bmix2 - (Bmix2)^2) z - (Amix2) (Bmix2) == 
        0, z]}, _Real]]
                        ]]
```

The issue is that the code is somewhat slow. It makes running the model costly. For example:

```
yfra = N@{3, 20, 75, 1, 1, 1}/100;

Plot[Table[fugacitymix[273 + 200, x*100000, i, yfra], {i, 1, 6}], {x, 
1, 300}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

Takes approximately 40s on my machine.

I tried compiling the function with:

```
cfugacity = 
Compile[{{temp, _Real}, {pres, _Real}, {i, _Integer}, {yfrac, _Real, 
6}},
With[{Amix2 = Amix[temp, pres, yfrac], 
Bmix2 = Bmix[temp, pres, yfrac]},
                        Exp[
                        (z - 1) B[temp, pres][[i]]/Bmix2 - Log[z - Bmix2] - 
  Amix2/Bmix2 (2 (A[temp, pres][[i]]/Amix2)^0.5 - 
     B[temp, pres][[i]]/Bmix2) Log[1 + Bmix2/z] /. 
 z -> Last[
   Cases[z /. {ToRules@
       NRoots[z^3 - 
          z^2 + (Amix2 - Bmix2 - (Bmix2)^2) z - (Amix2) (Bmix2) ==
          0, z]}, _Real]]
                            ]]
  ]

Plot[Table[cfugacity[273 + 200, x*100000, i, yfra], {i, 1, 6}], {x, 
1, 300}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

This one takes in fact longer than the uncompiled version, about 47s. I'm looking for suggestions to improve the speed.

Comment: [A related question.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9728)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The functions `Amix` and `Bmix` are called quite often with the same arguments. Memoization (see below) is a easily implementable way to speed the computations up. Moreover, the sum in `Bmix` can be rewritten as a simple `Dot`-product and the double sum in `Amix` can be also simplified tremendously. Try your code with these new definitions; it makes the execution about 80 times faster on my machine:

```
ClearAll[Amix, Bmix, A, B];

A[temp_, pres_] := (a alpha[temp]) (pres/(r*temp)^2);
B[temp_, pres_] := b (pres/(r*temp));

Bmix[temp_, pres_, yfrac_] := Bmix[temp, pres, yfrac] = yfrac.B[temp, pres];
Amix[temp_, pres_, yfrac_] := Amix[temp, pres, yfrac] = (yfrac.Sqrt[A[temp, pres]])^2;
```

**Edit**

I reworked the code a bit in the meantime. Due to Daniel Lichtblau's suggestion, I added memoization also for `A`, `B`, and `alpha`. Moreover, I removed the dependence of `A` and `B` on `pres` (they simply depend linearly on `pres`) so that fewer memoized values have to be computed. But most importantly, I vectorized `fugacitymix` along the argument `i` and I observed that the value of `z` can be reused for all `i`. These are the new parts of the code:

```
ClearAll[Amix0, Bmix0, A0, B0, alpha]

alpha[temp_] := alpha[temp] = (1. + (0.480 + 1.574 omegac - 0.176 omegac^2) (1 - Sqrt[temp/tempc]))^2;

A0[temp_] := A0[temp] = (a alpha[N[temp]]) (1./(r N[temp])^2);
B0[temp_] := B0[temp] = b (1./(r N[temp]));

Amix0[temp_, yfrac_] := Amix0[temp, yfrac] = (yfrac.Sqrt[A0[temp]])^2;
Bmix0[temp_, yfrac_] := Bmix0[temp, yfrac] = yfrac.B0[temp]

fugacitymix0[temp_, pres_?NumericQ, yfrac_] := Block[{Amix2, Bmix2, z, zz},
  Amix2 = Amix0[temp, yfrac] pres;
  Bmix2 = Bmix0[temp, yfrac] pres;
  z = Last[
    Cases[
     z /. {ToRules@NRoots[
           z^3 - z^2 + (Amix2 - Bmix2 - (Bmix2)^2) z - (Amix2) (Bmix2) == 0,
           z]}, _Real]
    ];
  Exp[(z - 1) pres B0[temp]/Bmix2 - Log[z - Bmix2] - 
    Amix2/Bmix2 (2. (pres A0[temp]/Amix2)^0.5 - pres B0[temp]/Bmix2) Log[1 + Bmix2/z]
   ]
  ]
```

And this is how it is used:

```
Plot[fugacitymix0[273 + 200, x*100000, yfra], {x, 1, 300}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

It performs the task in about 0.12 seconds.

Comment: It seems faster still to memoize `alpha,A,B`, and also to make the first arg to `fugacitymix` a machine double instead of integer.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thanks for the suggestions. I added them in a new edit.

Comment: Definitely a strong improvement over the original. However when I test the command for the plot, I receive a lot of error messages 
 such as "NRoots::nnumeq: -5.72408*10^-8 x^2+(-0.000370503 x-2.37987*10^-7 x^2) z-z^2+z^3==0 is expected to be a polynomial equation in the variable z with numeric coefficients." The task is eventually performed but it looks like there's some issue with evaluation. Is there a way around that ?

Comment: I added `pres_?NumericQ` to the argument pattern of `fugacitymix0`. This should inhibit the symbolic computation that causes the error.

Comment: I've seen that trick before and I was trying it too, but somehow it doesn't seem to help in that case (MMA 11.0).

Comment: I cleaned memory and now the error messages have disapeared. Incidentally, I was also wondering if there could be benefits from compiling. As I wrote in my OP, I tried it, but didn't observe any improvement.

Comment: Compiling would not help here because `NRoots` is not compilable. That means, you can create a `CompiledFunction` containing it but this compiled function will contain calls to Mathematica's evaluator. Usually that makes things _slower_ than the uncompiled version of the function due to communications overhead and waiting time. Moreover, memoization within `CompiledFunction`s has the same effect. The backend of `NRoots` is already compiled, so it is already fairly effficient.

Comment: You might be able to get away with compiling the Cardano-Tartaglia formula for the roots. Care must be taken to allow that the result can be complex even though input is real. Also it is not obvious whether this will offer any speed improvement.